# dsp on an UIImage

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get pixel data from a UIImage (Cocoa Touch) or CGImage (Core Graphics)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics)

Let's say I have a `UIImage` that I would like to get the rgb matrix of, in order to do some processing on it, not to change it, just get the `UIImage` data so i can use my C algorithms on it.
As you probably know, all the math is done on the image rgb matrixes.

Comment: @userxxx instead of randomly inserting unrelated code, make your question hit the quality standards of SO. There's no other way.

Comment: and before you do so, use the search!

Comment: @H2CO3 so, can you teach me how to do that ? i would like to know what do i have to change in order to make me be "quality" ? this is really interested me .

Comment: @user1280535 you have to post a specific question about a specific problem (that's good in this question as far as I can tell you). Your question should be written in good and understandable English. Then you should make sure your question cannot be answered using a simple google search or a search on StackOverflow (this one can). To complete all this, off-topic or spam (self-promoting and advertising) non-questions are not welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic procedure is to create a bitmap context with `CGBitmapContextCreate`, then draw your image into that context and get the internal data with `CGBitmapContextGetData`. Here's an example:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage.png"];

//Create the bitmap context:
CGImageRef cgImage = [image CGImage];
size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(cgImage);
size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(cgImage);
size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
size_t bytesPerRow = width * 4;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(); 
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
//Draw your image into the context:
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), cgImage);
//Get the raw image data:
unsigned char *data = CGBitmapContextGetData(context);

//Example how to access pixel values:
size_t x = 0;
size_t y = 0;
size_t i = y * bytesPerRow + x * 4;
unsigned char redValue = data[i];
unsigned char greenValue = data[i + 1];
unsigned char blueValue = data[i + 2];
unsigned char alphaValue = data[i + 3];
NSLog(@"RGBA at (%i, %i): %i, %i, %i, %i", x, y, redValue, greenValue, blueValue, alphaValue);

//Clean up:
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGContextRelease(context);
//At this point, your data pointer becomes invalid, you would have to allocate
//your own buffer instead of passing NULL to avoid this.
```